# transformar lista em dicionário python

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Minha lista e criada a partir de um laço while e ela traz todos os dados referentes as partidas que estão acontecendo. Eu quero pegar essa lista e transformar em um dicionário.

Obs: O nuumero de partidas na pé fixo ele depende da quantidade de jogos que estão acontecendo no momento.

Segue um exemplo da lista que meu script gera:

```
['FC Atl�tico Cearense', 'time casa', 'Icasa', 'time visitante', '0', 'gols casa', '0', 'gols visitante', '53', 'ataque casa', '50', 'ataque visitante', '2', 'amarelo casa', '0', 'vermelho casa', '2', 'escanteio casa', '5', 'escanteio visitante', '0', 'vermelho visitante', '4', 'amarelo visitante', 'Crato', 'time casa', 'Maracan�', 'time visitante', '0', 'gols casa', '0', 'gols visitante', '9', 'ataque casa', '21', 'ataque visitante', '0', 'amarelo casa', '0', 'vermelho casa', '0', 'escanteio casa', '1', 'escanteio visitante', '0', 'vermelho visitante', '0', 'amarelo visitante', 'Am�rica de Natal', 'time casa', 'Santa Cruz RN', 'time visitante', '1', 'gols casa', '0', 'gols visitante', '75', 'ataque casa', '77', 'ataque visitante', '2', 'amarelo casa', '0', 'vermelho casa', '7', 'escanteio casa', '3', 'escanteio visitante', '0', 'vermelho visitante', '2', 'amarelo visitante']
```

Eu sou novo em Python, então depois de pesquisar vi aqui no forum que podia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
y = 1
for elem in jogo[::2]:
    dic[jogo[y]] = elem
    y = y + 2
```

No entanto, quando eu executo não tenho o resultado pretendido, pois é retornado somente os dados da ultima partida,falaram nos comentários que é devido a duplicidade de chaves.

Segue o dicionário que é retornado usando esse método:

```
{'time casa': 'Am�rica de Natal', 'time visitante': 'Santa Cruz RN', 'gols casa': '1', 'gols visitante': '0', 'ataque casa': '75', 'ataque visitante': '77', 'amarelo casa': '2', 'vermelho casa': '0', 'escanteio casa': '7', 'escanteio visitante': '3', 'vermelho visitante': '0', 'amarelo visitante': '2'}
```

Eu gostaria de receber no dicionário todos os resultados da lista. Se alguém puder me ajudar ajustando esse método ou mostrando outra forma de como fazer isso eu agradeço

Comment: Dicionários não aceitam duplicidade de chaves. Toda vez que uma chave cujo o nome já exista no dicionário o valor anterior é sobrescrito. Outra coisa python é sensível ao recuo, se nos apresenta um código não endentado não podemos determinar com certeza o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: nesse caso como eu consigo gerar uma chave para cada repetição do while?

Comment: Uma sugestão, não precisa fazer desse jeito, você adicionar o valor de `y` ao nome da chave. Vão ficar assim: `'time casa1:...'`, `'time visitante1':....`, `'time casa2:...'`. Mas em minha opinião você poderia elaborar melhor a pergunta a transformando o exemplo num [mcve] onde tiraria a parte do scrapping e trabalhasse apenas a lista obtida e o dicionário, mostrando o exemplo de como fica e em seguida mostrasse como gostaria que ficasse e um critério para organizar os dados.

Comment: obrigado, vou editar a pergunta aqui

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa que talvez resolva seu problema seria criar um dicionário de dicionários. No exemplo abaixo sugiro uma solução na qual criamos um dicionário 'jogos', no qual cada elemento será um dicionário com os dados de cada jogo. As chaves são identificadas como 'jogo 1', 'jogo 2', etc.

Aqui fazemos uso da lista que você havia postado.

```
    lista = ['FC Atlético Cearense', 'time casa', 'Icasa', 'time visitante', '0', 'gols casa', '0', 'gols visitante', '53', 'ataque casa', '50', 'ataque visitante', '2', 'amarelo casa', '0', 'vermelho casa', '2', 'escanteio casa', '5', 'escanteio visitante', '0', 'vermelho visitante', '4', 'amarelo visitante', 'Crato', 'time casa', 'Maracana', 'time visitante', '0', 'gols casa', '0', 'gols visitante', '9', 'ataque casa', '21', 'ataque visitante', '0', 'amarelo casa', '0', 'vermelho casa', '0', 'escanteio casa', '1', 'escanteio visitante', '0', 'vermelho visitante', '0', 'amarelo visitante', 'America de Natal', 'time casa', 'Santa Cruz RN', 'time visitante', '1', 'gols casa', '0', 'gols visitante', '75', 'ataque casa', '77', 'ataque visitante', '2', 'amarelo casa', '0', 'vermelho casa', '7', 'escanteio casa', '3', 'escanteio visitante', '0', 'vermelho visitante', '2', 'amarelo visitante']
```

Partindo da sua lista de jogos, criamos a lista 'indices', que irá conter o índice de cada instância do item 'time casa', que servirá para estabelecer os limites de cada item do dicionário 'jogos'.

Depois, criamos uma estrutura de repetição para popular o dicionário jogos, com base nas entradas da sua lista.

```
    indices = [i for i in range(len(lista)) if lista[i] == 'time casa']
    
    jogos   = {}

    for n, indice in enumerate(indices):
        if n < len(indices)-1:
            jogos[f'Jogo {n+1}'] = dict(zip(lista[indice:indices[n+1]:2],lista[indice-1:indices[n+1]:2]))
        else:
            jogos[f'Jogo {n+1}'] = dict(zip(lista[indice::2],lista[indice-1::2]))
    jogos
```

Pronto. Agora temos um dicionário com 3 itens, cada um deles um único dicionário com os dados dos jogos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]